# How To Get/Compute Starting Balance From Plaid

Tags: plaid

Using Plaid in a consumer facing app.  When someone first links a bank account I only want to get the last 5 days worth of transactions (if any)... and then I want to compute what the "starting balance" was just before those transactions.  (Please just trust me that I need that "starting balance" for my app!)

My idea here is to get the `current` balance and then subtract off the transactions for the last 5 days.

The docs effectively say that the `/transactions/get` API is deprecated - and I should use `/transactions/sync`.  That's fine - but `/transactions/sync` doesn't provide the current account balance.

I could call `/accounts/balance/get`, but that causes a balance refresh that might give me a newer balance that includes transactions that have come in after I've been through `/transactions/sync`.

`/accounts/get` is another option - and seems to return the "cached" balance that is probably the correct balance that goes with the transactions that just came through from `sync`... but there is no guarantee.  It's definitely possible that Plaid could have updated their cached balance to one that includes transactions beyond what I just got from `sync`.

Basically: as far as I can tell, there is not a solution that uses `sync` and guarantees a current balance that perfectly matches.  Why in the heck doesn't `sync` return THE current balance that goes with the transactions that just came through?

So now - I feel like I'm going to use `/transactions/get`... because it WILL return the current balance *and* all of the transactions that went into the calculation of that balance.  Unfortunately, this may return a huge amount of data - and I'll just have to throw it all away other than the last 5 days.

My plan is this:

1. Link account
2. Receive `INITIAL` webhook
3. Call `/transactions/get`
4. Get all of the transactions, only keep the last 5 days worth
5. Pull the current balance out of the response
6. Subtract off the last 5 days worth of transactions to compute the "starting balance" before those.
7. Call `/transactions/sync` to tell Plaid that I want to use the `sync` API going forward.
8. Read all of the transactions from sync, throw away all transactions other than the last 5 days worth.
9. Verify that the last 5 days worth of transactions are the same (modify any that have changed, delete any that went away, add any new ones)
10. Carry on using `sync` going forward.

Am I crazy?  Is there a better way?!?

No errors - just unclear on the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In step 4, why not just get the last 5 days of transactions? `/transactions/get` allows you to specify the date range you want.
Note `/transactions/get` isn’t going away any time soon (it will probably never go away) we just don’t recommend it as it has a number of usability problems that `/transactions/sync` solves. If you find it better for your use case, it’s fine to use.
P.S. While it is theoretically possible that `/accounts/get` could return a different balance than `/transactions/sync`, if called immediately after, the odds of this happening should be so low as to be effectively zero.

EDIT TO ADD: The safe way to do it is: if you call `/transactions/sync`, then call `/accounts/get`, and then call `/transactions/sync` again and receive no new transactions, you can safely assume that the balance returned by `/accounts/get` is up-to-date with `/transactions/sync`. Alternatively, you can listen for webhooks and can safely assume that the balances are the same until you receive a `SYNC_UPDATES_AVAILABLE` webhook.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex.  You are right about step 4 - I'll make sure to call it only getting the last 5 days of transactions.  Is there any hope of getting the balance info from sync?  I also work on massively parallel software running on supercomputers... when you have millions of something happening, "vanishingly small" will eventually happen!!  ;-)

Comment: @friedmud OK, here's the guaranteed way to do it: if you call /transactions/sync, then call /accounts/get, and then call /transactions/sync again and receive no new transactions, you can safely assume that the balance returned by /accounts/get is up-to-date with /transactions/sync.

Comment: Thanks Alex - that makes sense.  The only edge case that I can see there is that there are times _right after_ account creation where `/transactions/sync` returns nothing because Plaid hasn't been able to pull anything yet.  I'm mitigating that by waiting to do this until I get the first hook call from Plaid saying there is sync data available.